# backend not responding with domain but responding with ip

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, web, dns

I have setup 2 different servers for frontend and backend. frontend server is accessible with ip and the domain both.

all api requests are being processed by backend long as it comes from the ip. but when i load the ui with domain name, the backend is not accepting requests. returns no response. I have already configured in my application, so this seems like some problem with some aws config.. please help.

both are smallest aws ec2,
frontend is nextjs
backend is django

Comment: If I do "disable protection for now" for https, it's working..

Comment: Are both your frontend and backend on the same domain? If so, are they using different subdomains? Also, have you checked your DNS configs for both?

Comment: @wandering-geek they're on different servers. frontend has a domain backend doesn't

Comment: If the backend doesn't have a domain, then how do you expect it to respond when you try to access it via a domain?

Comment: The problem was that my frontend domain had https (ssl cert) but backend was being accessed over http directly via IP. I configured a subdomain for backend, gave it ssl and it worked!!!